# Where were these castle pictures from WW II taken?

Tags: europe, germany, identify-this, architecture

I have four pictures taken during WWII but one of them isn't so great, although it does seem to show a tall tower within the building somewhere (added this pic--view from hill in back of castle). My Dad took these pics somewhere in Europe, perhaps France, Czechslovakia, Belgium or Germany. He's nearly 93 and can't remember where it was. A name and location would be nice. It looks kind of cool, but the pictures are so close up that it's hard to tell the overall look of the place. Perhaps that oddly-roofed turret tower may help.

[image: turret]
[image: wall]
[image: wall ivy]
[image: castle from hill in rear]
[image: enhanced BG pic #1]

Comment: No need to say that no search engine helps here ... :(

Comment: No, Matt, I've tried a bit. But I recently received lots of info about the "route" he may have taken while he was in Europe, so maybe some long days searching each town might find something. But I'm in the middle of another project right now. And thanks for looking/trying.

Comment: Deleted a lot: It seems this was somewhere in Meurthe-et-Moselle, Moselle, or Bas-Rhin region of France...mostly Alsace/Lorraine in “mountainous” terrain.

The building was on a hill with a river below it. A closer look at pic 1 reveals the "turret" of some other building down over the wall and trees "below"...plus the wall itself (left of frame). And pic 2 does look like a hill with trees to the right of frame, behind the building. Perched on a serious slope? Also, pic 3 looks like maybe from below the wall somewhere (foreground) with crenelations(?) going off to right and going "uphill"?

Comment: Dad was a replacement to the 313th Infantry of the 79th Division. He joined with 313th at Luneville. Route then goes to Foret De Porroy (many of these are attacks), Embermenil, withdraw to Rosieres, Armistice Day celebration 11-11-44 in Luneville again, then”race” to Strasbourg thru Saverne Gap of Vosges Mts, then thru Bischwiller Haguenau to Lauter River and Lauterbourg, then into Germany. 313th later relieved by 101st airborne and withdrew to rest at Mousson, France—later from there to Maastricht, Holland.

Comment: Why not edit your comments into the question so people see the whole thing? You could also edit the title to attract people who might know those areas.

Comment: That turrettower is easily identified if you know the castle. Unfortunately I don't. And there are many castles in the region you mention, [here is a list of the Belgian castles](https://nl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijst_van_kastelen_in_België) for example. Looking at the style, I'd say France is most likely, but I can't be sure.

Comment: I scrolled through all the images here: http://www.castlesandmanorhouses.com/photos.htm . The closest in appearance is Veste Coburg (IMO). Given the turret in photo 1, this seems like a German castle. Also note that the leaves have fallen yet there is no snow on the ground. IIRC, the winter of 44-45 was pretty harsh; this may provide a clue as to the when the photos were taken. From there you might be able to find some historical record or your Dad's unit's travels and narrow down the locations to search. Good luck!

Comment: If you have not seen this, http://digicom.bpl.lib.me.us/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1192&context=ww_reg_his , it may help to nail down dates and places. And in reference to my comment above, there was no snow on the ground in mid-December 1944 (where the 313th was), so I was wrong about the harsh winter.

Comment: I know roughly where both units were, & when. My problem is if he took the pics on his way to join the 313th or after he had joined & all I have are noted "battle" movements. If before he "joined", we're not sure where he was. He said yesterday he was on trucks and they were traveling, most of the time not even knowing where they were. So, I'm assuming in transit...but I still think somewhere in Alsace/Lorraine regions. He did say it was on a "rocky" pretty high hill. That area has the Vosges Mts. & other "terrain"? My best guess now is in that area & seemingly somewhere in Sept/Oct of 44.

Comment: But it could have been also (I suppose) during the withdrawal to Rosiers, then back to Luneville. Not sure where Rosiers is...but that would be into November. So, if your question about no leaves may make that more likely?...I don't know. Movement info says Rosiers is 50K west, I guess of Embermenil. I followed part of the Vezouze river using Bing maps aerial (because he said there was a river below the hill/castle), but it's hard to do. I saw nothing of note. But rivers are hard to see and follow, as are noting specific towns--there's just so much "clutter". I do plan on trying more though.

Comment: Sorry to run on but, if you look really hard at the 1st pic, there are definitely other buildings in the background, below the courtyard/garden wall. Some really faded/indistinct. So...above a village/city? Could the other "turret" there be a church steeple?

Comment: If you look to the right of the turret in photo 1, a little past the center of the photo, you can see trees. I think photo 4 may have been taken where those trees are (not that this helps in finding out where it is). As for the other turret, yes, I think it may be a steeple or bell tower. Looking at the full sized scans reveals quite a bit of detail. If you have a photo editor, you might play with brightness/contrast to see if there is helpful detail hiding.

Comment: Also, the statuary in photo 1 may be a clue: Half nude, on a pedestal. This may have been common across Europe at some point, or it may be specific to a region.

Comment: I believe pic 2 is reverse of pic 1--very left of frame is the turret tower (with wall we see in background of 1 behind camera), looking back toward where 1 was taken but up the wall. The trees to the far right of pic 2 are the trees we're looking thru in pic 4 I think--pic 4 labeled "from hill in rear", so taken "behind the castle", before entering courtyard. And I've puzzled about perspective/location of pic 3, except perhaps somewhere below the wall in pic 1. Or the other side of the building? It's looking more directly at the roof/wall in 1 & 2 (rt angles), but there's NO ivy in 1 or 2?

Comment: Actually, #1 is probably above courtyard, not in it?

Comment: OK added an enlarged view of background of #1. DEFINITELY more stuff below that wall-note steep roof in center and lots of stuff to the right, not to miss the "steeple?" to left. I don't have original pic so this was the best I could do with copy I have and not great software, but you can see better. Working on getting better, enlarged etc copy of that area of #1 from sister.

Comment: Looking at the shadows and sun angles, it's very hard to guess about #3; I thought it was the opposite side of the main building from #1 and #2, but unless your father was taking pics from sunrise to near sunset, I don't think that's possible. IIRC, dates of processing were sometimes (very lightly) printed on the backs of photographic prints. @droonfang Can you ask your sister to look for any such info?

Comment: Does anyone still have the negatives? It might be possible to recognise something before or after and narrow down the area to be searched.

Comment: No negatives but now noting pictures developed In Schweinfurt. But he took the pictures all over the place. But, WOW this looks very similar but I can't see any tower on it in pics I've found. Schloss Mainberg. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schloss_Mainberg.jpg

Comment: To indicate that the question has been answered you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark below the voting buttons.

Comment: I can't accept yet. I answered my own question and have to wait.

Comment: Wonderful find! In the satellite pics on goolag maps, it looks like the ivy is winning...

Comment: Thx...and there's the river below it too. It's the Main, which is why it's called "Mainberg"? Oh, well...he just had the whole wrong country...but, he's 93. One of the last WWII guys? If you look up Schweinfurt at Wikipedia, it will tell you why his unit went thru there.

Comment: Yeah, my Dad's a 92 year old WWII vet entering the late stages of dementia... that's why your question resonated with me.

Comment: I was very exited, when I saw your pictures today. I'm interested in informations and pictures about Schloss Mainberg, because I am from Schonungen. In May an association (Förderverein Schloss Mainberg) has been founded, which is committed to the renovation of the damaged castle.
Here you can read and see more about the location an the club: https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=freundeskreis%20schloss%20mainberg
https://www.ardmediathek.de/tv/Frankenschau-aktuell/Wie-geht-s-weiter-mit-Schloss-Mainberg/BR-Fernsehen/Video?bcastId=14913732&documentId=52134472

Comment: I don't do facebook so your link doesn't do anything for me. As far as info, my best advice is to check with Maria Shipley at her blog. Contact her; she's very helpful and she published this page with my Dad's photos and one of him. Tell her I sent you if you like. http://www.maria-shipley.de/mainberg-castle/mainberg-castle-in-germany-in-the-1940s/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This really may be it. Schloss Mainberg in Schonungen, Germany (not Schweinfurt, I guess?). And all purely by accident that it was probably taken in the same place the pics were developed! Note faint red circles around turret dome and steeple. Glad I stopped looking in France.
Don't miss this either-just found it-if you'd like to see more.
http://s60.photobucket.com/user/mordfilm/slideshow/Schloss%20Mainberg
And this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IRoidJzNk0

[image: with tower outlined]
[image: steeple outlined]

Comment: This link may be of interest to some "travelers" as this site is a travel site. And is a bit of an addition to this post and answer as well. I think she posts other things to see in Germany as well. http://www.maria-shipley.de/mainberg-castle/mainberg-castle-in-germany-in-the-1940s/

Comment: Confirmed by castle historian. My Dad's photos are indeed of Mainberg castle!